# How to add custom layers on the new Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is posible to add a custom layers to the new Google Maps SDK for iOS? 
  *Custom layers in Tile images or in KML format.

In the documentation I see nothing about layers.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not in this initial version.  There is some hope though as the similar Android API has one.

I can only suggest raising a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list)

Comment: There is a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4711